# problem with windows forms application settings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have used Visual Studio to generate a class for application settings in a windows forms application. The application settings aren't populated with values when debugging. Why are there no values?

Here is the generated code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.1
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Unidata_Client.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "10.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("blah")]
        public string UnidataUsername {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["UnidataUsername"]));
            }
            set {
                this["UnidataUsername"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("blah")]
        public string UnidataPassword {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["UnidataPassword"]));
            }
            set {
                this["UnidataPassword"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("blah")]
        public string UnidataHost {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["UnidataHost"]));
            }
            set {
                this["UnidataHost"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("123")]
        public string UnidataPort {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["UnidataPort"]));
            }
            set {
                this["UnidataPort"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("blah")]
        public string UnidataAccount {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["UnidataAccount"]));
            }
            set {
                this["UnidataAccount"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="Unidata_Client.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <Unidata_Client.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="UnidataUsername" serializeAs="String">
                <value>blah</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="UnidataPassword" serializeAs="String">
                <value>blah </value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="UnidataHost" serializeAs="String">
                <value>blah</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="UnidataPort" serializeAs="String">
                <value>123</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="UnidataAccount" serializeAs="String">
                <value>blah</value>
            </setting>
        </Unidata_Client.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here is how I am using the settings:

```
 using (var session = UniObjects.OpenSession(Settings.Default.UnidataHost,
                int.Parse(Settings.Default.UnidataPort),
                Settings.Default.UnidataUsername,
                Settings.Default.UnidataPassword,
                Settings.Default.UnidataAccount,
                "udcs"))
            {
                .....
            }
```

Comment: You specified no additional details, and there isn't really anything anyone could offer you without far more explanation.

Comment: Can you post the code for how you are accessing the settings?  Also, can you post your app.config file?

Comment: When you say not populated when debugging, do you mean when stepping through in the debugger or when running the application in debug mode?

Comment: I mean when running the application in debug mode.

Comment: Will the downvoters please remove the downvotes? I have provided as much info as possible.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all files in your debug output folder and rebuilding the application from scratch?  Do this process for both the debug and release output folders, rebuild, and see if there is a difference between the way the two version run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using "usersettings" (scope "user" in the designer).
When changed (not default) these settings are stored somewhere in your personal profile.
These settings override the ones in the directory of your application

Could you try to change the settings to scope "application" in the designer and run again ?

If you have values then, u can be sure the usersettings are overridden in your profile directory.

Look for a file user.config in C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\ApplicationName\Version\

Comment: In VS2013 (not sure about other versions), you have a small button called `Synchronize` [see screenshot here](http://i.imgur.com/QC3iV5B.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is your app.config being copied and renamed to MyApp.exe.config in your debug output directory?

Comment: And if you are running with a debugger attached, are the settings present in the MyApp.vshost.exe.config file?